# Bash : Command line argument issue

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

```
#usernamecheck.sh 

#!/bin/bsh
DBUSER=user_1
DBPASSWORD=XXXXX
DBSOURCENAME=database_1
DBNAME=database_1
DBNAME1=snapshot_v
DBSERVER=X.X.X.X
DBCONN="-h ${DBSERVER} -u ${DBUSER} --password=${DBPASSWORD}"

echo "select user from device_id where ip='1.1.1.1'|mysql $DBCONN $DBNAME
```

The output of executing this script is:

```
user
----
JohnDoe
```

The above bash script which gives me user name of IP (1.1.1.1). I would like to pass the IP as a command line argument. I tried,

```
echo "select user from device_id where ip=$1|mysql $DBCONN $DBNAME
```

and executed like

```
$./usernamecheck.sh '1.1.1.1'
```

I get the error message:

> Error in SQL syntax

Hope i'm passing the command line argument correct. But not sure, why does this error pop up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a query, you say:

```
WHERE ip='1.1.1.1'
```

What you are currently saying is:

```
WHERE ip=$1
```

which gets translated to

```
WHERE ip=1.1.1.1
```

So you are missing a quote around `$1` to make it work:

```
WHERE ip='$1'
#        ^  ^
```

All together:

```
echo "select user from device_id where ip='$1' | mysql $DBCONN $DBNAME
#                                         ^  ^
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked perfect !